# Why is it called "The LOFAR 'superterp'"? What is a terp, and what's so super about this one?

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, terminology, naming, lofar

Wikipedia's [Low-Frequency Array (LOFAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Frequency_Array_(LOFAR)) includes the image below with the caption:

> The LOFAR core ("superterp") near Exloo, Netherlands. The bridges give an idea of the scale.

**Question:** Why is it called "The LOFAR 'superterp'"? What is a terp, and what's so super about this one?

B. W. Stappers et al. (2011) [Observing pulsars and fast transients with LOFAR](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1577) may offer clues:

> A schematic diagram of some of the LOFAR stations in the inner core
> of LOFAR − the “Superterp” as it is known − is shown in Figure 1.

[image: Fig. 1. Three successive zoom-outs showing the stations in the LOFAR core. The different scales of the hierarchically organised HBA elements are highlighted and their respective beam sizes are shown. The large circular area marks the edge of the Superterp, which contains the inner-most 6 stations...]

> Fig. 1. Three successive zoom-outs showing the stations in the LOFAR core. The different scales of the hierarchically organised
> HBA elements are highlighted and their respective beam sizes are shown. **The large circular area marks the edge of the Superterp,
> which contains the inner-most 6 stations** (i.e. 12 HBA sub-stations: where there are 2 sub-stations, each of 24 tiles, in each HBA
> core station); other core stations can be seen highlighted beyond the Superterp in the third panel. Left: a single HBA tile and
> associated beam. Middle: A single HBA sub-station with three simultaneous station beams. Right: The 6 stations of the Superterp
> plus 3 core stations in the background are highlighted. Four independent beams formed from the coherent combination of all 24
> core HBA stations, most of which are outside this photo, are shown. For the LBA stations, a similar scheme applies except that
> each LBA dipole can effectively see the whole sky. Fields of the relatively sparsely distributed LBA antennas are visible in between
> the highlighted HBA stations in all three panels.

---

[image: The LOFAR 'superterp'. This is part of the core of the extended telescope located near Exloo, Netherlands.]

Source: [File:LOFAR Superterp.jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LOFAR_Superterp.jpg)

> - Description, English: The LOFAR 'superterp'. This is part of the core of the extended telescope located near Exloo, Netherlands.
> - Date: 23 May 2010
> - Source: http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/news/2011/LOFAR-pulsars/
> - Author: LOFAR / ASTRON

Comment: Because it looks a bit like a [turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maryland_Terrapins)? My wife was/is a Terp. Obviously not an answer.

Comment: Trans-Exclusionary Radical Pfluggerhagen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Terp is a Frisan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terp#West_Frisian) and Dutch word meaning a low artificial hill for shelter during a high tide. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terp). Before dykes were built, farmstead were built on *terpen* to protect them from the frequent floods.

This is super because it is so much bigger than the small *terpen* that Frisian farmers would make to be safe from floods.

Comment: *Excellent!* Well done.